# How can integrate the square of a 3D Gaussian distribution?

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

While [I understand how we can integrate the usual one-dimensional Gaussian distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125233/show-that-integral-of-gaussian-distribution-is-1)
$$ I =  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(\sigma)^2} , $$ 
I'm currently struggling with its three-dimensional analogue:

$$ I = \int d^3x  \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})^2}{\sigma^2}} .$$
Substituting $\vec z \equiv \frac{(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}')}{\sigma}$ we find
\begin{align} I &= \int  d^3z \, \sigma \mathrm{e}^{-(\vec{z})^2} \\
&=   \sigma  \int dz_1 \mathrm{e}^{-(z_1)^2}  \int dz_2 \mathrm{e}^{-(z_2)^2}  \int dz_3 \mathrm{e}^{-(z_3)^2} \\
&= \sigma \sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{\pi} \\
&= \sigma \sqrt{\pi}^3 \, .
\end{align}
**Is this correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not correct, the final answer should be $$ I_1^3=\sigma^3\,(\pi\cdot)^{3/2}$$, where $I_1$ is the integral in one dimension. Your idea was in principle right but you have to be more careful with the substitution, take into account that $d^3z=\frac{d^3x}{\sigma^3}$.

Comment: thanks! Using this modification, however,  I end up with $\sigma^3 \sqrt{\pi}^3$ instead of  $\sqrt{\sigma \pi}^3$. The factor $\sigma^3$ is a result of the modified norm and I don't see why it should become $\sqrt{\sigma}^3$

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, you are right! I edited my answer.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot!