# How to find a constant in Gaussian function

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this probability distribution:

$$f(x) = a\exp\left(-\frac{(x-b)^2}{2c^2}\right)$$

I know constant $b = 0, c = 9.49$ and area under the curve is equal to $1$. How to calculate constant $a$ when I can't integrate the function?

Comment: why can't you integrate?

Comment: There is no closed form antiderivative for a Gaussian, but one *can* evaluate the indefinite integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f$.  This is a pretty standard exercise, and has been answered on Math SE before.  See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125233/show-that-integral-of-gaussian-distribution-is-1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the substitution $u=\frac{x-b}{\sqrt2 c}$, you obtain:
$$1=a\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{(x-b)^2}{2c^2}\right)\,dx=\sqrt{2}ac\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-u^2\right)\,du=\sqrt{2\pi}ac.$$
Now you can solve for $a$ since you know the value of $c$.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!