# How to calculate the integral equal to $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

By the definition of the gamma function:
$$\Gamma(n)=\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx}$$
Let $n = \frac{1}{2}$ and we get:
$$\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\int_0^{\infty}{e^{-x}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}dx}$$
I tried to use integration by parts but treating $x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ as $u$ or as $v$ both makes it needlessly complicated and doesn't seem to get me anywhere.
I then tried the subtitution $u=e^{-x}$, where $x=-\ln(u)$ and $dx=-\frac{1}{u}du$ gives me this new integral:
$$\int_1^0{\frac{u}{\sqrt{\ln(u)}}\cdot\frac{1}{u}du}=\int_1^0{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\ln(u)}}du}$$
However, I've not studied enough analysis to know if this integral is equivalent to $\int_0^1{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\ln(u)}}du}$ where I just swap the bounds like that, and even if I try to integrate it without particularly caring for the limits I get stuck. WolframAlpha gives the answer to this $u$ integral in terms of the imaginary error function, and it gives the answer to my original integral in terms of the very gamma function I started with! I know that $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}$ but I wanna figure out how we derive it!

Comment: Hint: Use $x=\frac{1}{2}t^2$. Then you get something that looks like the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). For a proof of the integral of the normal distribution, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1125233/407833)

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{-1/2}d x=2\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}d t=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: Yes, thank you @ReinhardMeier for the substitution I couldn't think of.